# using `switch`/`cond` in a custom loss function

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, loss-function

I need to implement a custom loss function in keras that computes the standard categorical crossentropy except when the `y_true` is all zeros.

This is my attempt to do so:

```
def masked_crossent(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.switch(K.any(y_true),
                    losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred),
                    losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred) * 0)
```

However, I get the following error once training starts (compilation works fine):

> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in **init**(self, graph, fetches, feeds)
>       419         self._ops.append(True)
>       420       else:
>   --> 421         self._assert_fetchable(graph, fetch.op)
>       422         self._fetches.append(fetch_name)
>       423         self._ops.append(False)
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in _assert_fetchable(self, graph, op)
>       432     if not graph.is_fetchable(op):
>       433       raise ValueError(
>   --> 434           'Operation %r has been marked as not fetchable.' % op.name)
>       435 
>       436   def fetches(self):
>
> ValueError: Operation 'IsVariableInitialized_4547' has been marked as
>   not fetchable.

In place of `losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred) * 0`, I've also tried the following with various other errors (either during compilation or once training has started):

```
                    K.zeros_like(losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred))

                    K.zeros((K.int_shape(y_true)[0]))

                    K.zeros((K.int_shape(y_true)[0], 1))
```

... though I imagine that there is a trivial way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only have an idea for a workaround:

```
def masked_crossent(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.max( y_true ) * K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
```

You need to add the `axis = -1` if this is for whole batches.